# Macbook Air OS X 10.8.4 Trackpad Pinch Zoom not working in Firefox 23.0.1

Tags: trackpad

I recently updated my OS X to 10.8.4 and updated Firefox to 23.0.1
Now the pinch zoom feature on my trackpad does not work. It works fine in Safari. Will appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore the zoom feature by changing the values of the related prefs on the about:config page.

```
browser.gesture.pinch.in -> cmd_fullZoomReduce
browser.gesture.pinch.in.shift -> cmd_fullZoomReset
browser.gesture.pinch.out -> cmd_fullZoomEnlarge
browser.gesture.pinch.out.shift -> cmd_fullZoomReset
browser.gesture.pinch.latched -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the specious answer would be "Use Safari", but that's clearly not very helpful.

I doubt very much that the OS update you mention made a difference, although for peace of mind you might like to step your upgrade to see where the fault was introduced.  If you can revert to your previous version of Firefox whilst keeping on 10.8.4 and see if that still works, then you'll know the problem is localised to the new Firefox version.